# Javascript: change the 'Refresh' button into 'Abort' (on the address bar)

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a one-page website. When the user clicks a link, the code like following fires:

```
loadDataWithXHR();
displayTheNewPage();
```

Since the `loadDataWithXHR()` may take some time (especially on slower network), I would like the browser to change the Refresh button (next to the address bar) into Abort button - just like when a document is being loaded by the browser itself.

Even if there is a library to do that, I'm interested in pure JavaScript approach - I want to learn how it works (if it's possible) and I don't want to include a potentially huge file in order to do one thing.

Comment: As far as I can remember, there is no way to change the address bar buttons (since they relies on the browser itself).
You can alter the `pageActions` through browser extensions, but that's not your case.
You should rather implement a button inside the page that clearly tells the user that such button is going to abort the call: it would be more intuitive and more user friendly, since users expects the refresh button to actually always refresh the page and they expect such button to actually always be there.

Comment: I don't think your JS can control browser. These buttons are for actual page state, not some XHR request. Maybe try setting `XMLHttpRequest.timeout` to smaller number?